# Rendered image sequence is darker then images (filmic or standard / H264 MPEG4)

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, color-management, encoding

What title says. Here is a screenshot, the red outlined one is the animation. It is way darker then the images. I tried color Management set to Filmic and Standard. Below are also my Encoding settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first thing I see is, in the _Color Management_ settings you have _Follow Scene_ enabled, so I guess the MP4 was rendered with the same settings as the image sequence. However, I see the _Exposure_ is set to -2.503 which seems quite dark to me for an interior scene (okay, it depends on how much light you put into that scene) and fitting to the look of the MP4. I have to ask, are you sure you didn't change settings between rendering the image sequence and the MP4?

Comment: The other thing is what is not quite clear from the question: did you render an image sequence and an MP4? Or did you import the image sequence and rendered an MP4 from that? Because in the latter case this would mean, you had a low exposure when rendering the images, and then you darken the images again by the low exposure, so they are twice darkened.

Comment: Hi, I rendered still images and then imported those to render an MP4. The Exposure is quite dark, because my light is relativly strong (Tried a bunch and I liked it this way). I just rendered with exposure set to 0 and it really lightend up my animation. I thought it just takes the images and puts them together. If I now change the exposure I will never get the exact sdame though as my images right? because Exposure set to 0 is now lighter then my original images

Comment: When you render a scene, the render is kind of a RAW image, displayed with the _Color Management_ settings. Changing exposure or look from medium contrast to high contrast etc. will change how the image is displayed. As soon as you save the image as PNG, these settings are fixed in the saved pixels. Reimporting them with will take the already changed pixels in the image and will apply the settings again on them. So with a pre-rendered image sequence in PNG format it would be best to set _Color Management_ to _Standard_ and _Look_ to _None_ to get the originally saved appearance.

Comment: A quick tip: if you save the image sequence with OpenEXR instead of PNG, it is saved as a kind of RAW image and the _Color Management_ can be applied to it. If you then also set the _Codec_ to "DWAA (lossy)" you have no noticeable loss in quality but the EXR files are even much smaller than PNG files.

Comment: _Color Management_ to _Standard_, _Look_ to _None_, _Exposure_ to 0 and _Gamma_ to 1 is what I forgot to say. That's how to get the original look of the saved PNG and how it would be displayed in other image editing software (at least if you don't use some kind of fancy color management there as well).